# carbide c++ symbian compiler error

Tags: c++, symbian, nokia, carbide

I have created a project on carbide c++ and I am getting an error

```
sbs returned with exit value = 1
```

I didn't make any changes on the code that carbide created.I am just created and build the project its throws the error.

I googled the error and could not find any solution. Does anyone get this error code before ?

Comment: post some more error / warning messages that you get before

Answer (score 0):

I was taking the same error...

Try to change the options of build...

That occurs when I was trying to compile using the armv5 instead of GCCE.

Change it and your problem could be resolved.

I´m new on symbian/carbide but it solved my problem!